# Calculate value of expressions based on solution of given linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra

I have these three equations:

```
1/X + 1/Y == 1/15;
1/Y + 1/Z == 1/20;
1/Z + 1/X == 1/25;
```

I want to calculate the value of expression:

```
1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z
```

Here is what I tried:

1. `FullSimplify[1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z]` which only returns `1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z`.
2. `Evaluate[1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z]` which also gives `1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z`.

Is there any way to calculate the value of this expression and other such expressions in Mathematica.

I could do this by hand by simply adding all these equations and then dividing by 2.

```
2*(1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z) == 1/15 + 1/20 + 1/25;
```

However, how can I use Mathematica to calculate the value for me using just the first three eqautions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Solve[{1/X + 1/Y == 1/15, 1/Y + 1/Z == 1/20, 1/Z + 1/X == 1/25}, {X, Y, Z}]
1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z /. %[[1]]
```

> ```
> {{X -> 600/17, Y -> 600/23, Z -> 600/7}}
>
> 47/600
> ```

---

```
Eliminate[{r == 1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z, 1/X + 1/Y == 1/15, 1/Y + 1/Z == 1/20, 1/Z + 1/X == 1/25}, {X, Y, Z}]
```

> ```
> 600 r == 47
> ```

---

```
Reduce[{r == 1/X + 1/Y + 1/Z, 1/X + 1/Y == 1/15, 1/Y + 1/Z == 1/20, 1/Z + 1/X == 1/25}, {X, Y, Z}]
```

> ```
> r == 47/600 && X == 600/17 && Y == 600/23 && Z == 600/7
> ```

Comment: Thanks Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ :)

What does `/. %[[1]]` do here?

Comment: @RealNoob Please check with `ReplaceAll`, `Out` and `Part`.

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
Total[LinearSolve[{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, 1/{15, 20, 25}]]
```

Comment: (I'm on *gedanken Mathematica*; can someone verify if this works?)

Comment: @Yes, It gives 47/600

Comment: Thanks JM. Could you please explain how this works. I read the documentation but it is still confusing. You did not use any of the variables here. :)

Comment: Before anything else @Real: what do you know about matrices?

Comment: @RealNoob matrix of the coefficients.